# Android if and else if statement not working

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to use the following code to show one intent if the record count is = too or greater then 5 and a different intent if the record count is less then 5 on the first button of a dashboard layout.

But I keep getting the evil NullPointError..........Am I on the right track or am I flapping in the wind, please help and point out what i'm doing wrong...Thanks

```
private class DashboardClickListener implements OnClickListener {
   // @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = null;
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.dashboard_button_one:
                if (mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes().getCount() >= 5){
                i = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, Demo.class);} 
                else if (mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes().getCount() < 5){
                i = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, one.class);}
                    break;
            case R.id.dashboard_button_two:
                i = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, two.class);             
                break;
            case R.id.dashboard_button_three:
                i = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, three.class);                   
                break;
            case R.id.dashboard_button_four:
                i = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, four.class);                   
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        if(i != null) {
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `NullPointError..` add your logcat...

Comment: Which line is the `NullPointerException` raised on?

Comment: Did you instantiate your mDbHelper? Open the DB?

Comment: post your logcat.. and check your fetchAllNotes() function for null.

Comment: Thanks Barak opening the DB did the trick...No more NullPoint, but now regardless of the record count it only goes to the Demo.Class and not the one.class when the record count is less then 5......Whats wrong with the GetCount ????

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I'll post that as an answer, if you could accept it (click the check mark next to it), that'd be great.  That lets everyone know your issue has been resolved and gives the person that helps you out credit.  And good job on posting a new question for a new issue.  I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you instantiate your mDbHelper? Open the DB?